# Arduino Mega connect to 2.1 speakers

Tags: arduino-mega

I am new to Arduino and I want to connect it to my 2.1 speakers and later to a 5.1 surround system.

The purpose is to play some wav sounds when a button is clicked or when a trip laser is cut. What should I do in order to play those wav around through the speakers? I also have an SD shield.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to divide your project into manageable blocks: Input, sound generation, reading wavs from SD card, etc. Which part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: i am having trouble making the speaker play the wav files i have in my SD. the speaker i have for test is an 8 Ohm speaker and when i finish with that i want to connect it to my 2.1 speaker system.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to figure out the bandwidth requirements and if this is possible at all. You need to do some basic calculations and answer the question if the Arduino and the different components have the bandwidth (byte/second) that is required.

The Arduino MCU (AVR) is too "weak" to do this on it's own. A special shield is required. Such as https://www.adafruit.com/products/1788

The Arduino Due has more processing power but still not stereo quality; https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer

More info to be googled.

Cheers!